# Chrome https insecure using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

basically my issue is that on my site I see i have a a connection thats going over http. I dont know how to change it.

```
<svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

I think this causes chrome to think my website is insecure. I have made my wordpress site on a raspberry pi zero with raspbian lite. I was thinking of changing the site via the website files but im not sure where to find them. I have looked in /var/www/html and have found nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: I use SVG graphics all the time and the xmlns definitions in them do not make the site unsecure. All of my sites with an SSL certificate display a nice green padlock and say Secure in Chrome, Firefox & Safari.

Comment: Thanks, after reading this comment i thought it might be somewhere else. I found it :D. It was my home button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my problem. Basically, the menu bar on my page had a button that goes to the homepage of my site. When i looked at that button, its URL was my local ip, 192.168.x.x. As my local ip cant have a certificate, the browser thinks its insecure. I changed that to my site home thats' html.dynu.net. Went back to my site sometime later and it was secured.

p.s. Usually for people, you buy an SSL certificate. Not anymore! I used Lets Encrypt and got a high quality grade A certificate :D